# input control of cmd created with C language CreateProcess()

Tags: c, windows

I want to open the cmd window using the CreateProcess function and enter the command "cd .." three times.

I want to control the input by specifying hStdInput in the STARTINFO structure as the pipe handle.

The first "cd .." command works normally.
The second one displays words  “More?”
The third has no any action.

My question is following two:

1. How do I fix it so that it will work correctly when I enter the command multiple times?
2. What is the reason it doesn’t work right now?

   ```
   VOID WriteToPipe(VOID) {

   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;

   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];

   CHAR cmds[] = "cd..";


       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {

           WriteFile(hChildStdinWrDup, cmds, sizeof(cmds), &dwWritten, NULL);
       }

   // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading.
   if (!CloseHandle(hChildStdinWrDup))
       ErrorExit("Close pipe failed");
    }
   ```

Comment: Can you try calling `SetFilePointer(hChildStdinWrDup,0,NULL,FILE_BEGIN);` after each of your write operations?

Comment: I'm quite rusty at this, but you should be able to attach a command line to your own process and communicate with it directly, without the need for IPC. Unless of course the whole purpose of this code is to practice IPC.

Comment: That being said, I suspect that you might have to transmit CR+LF with the command. That is, `CHAR cmds[] = "cd..\r\n";`.